# \hline doesn't compile ('arydshln' and 'tabularx' incompatibility)

Tags: tables, tabularx, arydshln

The code below

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{arydshln}   % These two packages aren't needed in this code because it's a minimal example, 
\usepackage{tabularx}   % but they're included because they're the source of the error.

\begin{document}

  \begin{tabular}{c}
    line 1 \\
    \hline
    line 2   
  \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

gives an error about ``\hline'':

```
\adl@hline ...mpcnta \xdef \adl@rowsL {\adl@rowsL
                                                   (#1/\number 
\@tempcnta );}... l.10     \hline
                 ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load `tabularx` before `arydshln`.

The code below works as expected.

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tabular}{c}
    line 1 \\
    \hline
    line 2   
  \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```